# Change Billing State API for Microsoft Store UWP apps?

Tags: uwp, in-app-purchase, azure-active-directory, windows-store

As per the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/change-the-billing-state-of-a-subscription-for-a-user), the user's billing state may be changed from the app developer's server for Microsoft Store UWP apps.

In the `changeType`, for the `Cancel` and `Refund` cases, does it cancel the running subscription or the next to be renewed?

Microsoft charges the user's card sometime within the current cycle for the next cycle. It might occur that user chooses to turn off the renewal, after the store has charged. In that case, whether the store will automatically refund or the developer need to refund using the above API.

Also, for cancellation, is it an immediate cancellation (with or without refunds for the remaining period?) or cancellation for the next cycle (just a server side utility).

Also, how these workflows will affect the `recurrenceState` property in the response of [Get subscriptions for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user) API

Answer (score 1):

> In that case, whether the store will automatically refund or the developer need to refund using the above API.

These are Microsoft's Terms of Service. Please see the `Payment Terms` of [Service document](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/servicesagreement/).

Other issues related to the Microsoft Store service, please consult the Microsoft Store staff. [Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/28808/microsoft-store-contact-support).

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not sure if the how the payment terms answer the above question. The payment terms are mostly from the user's perspective while the question asked here is from the developer's perspective implementing subscriptions in the app. The user shall not be concerned as to who initiates the refund.

Also, the payment terms say that any payment is non-refundable.

Comment: Hi, First, Microsoft stated in the Terms of Service that in most cases, no refunds will be made. When the user chooses to cancel the subscription, the subscription for the next cycle is canceled. When the user operates, the `recurrenceState` property changes and the developer can get the state to adjust when the software starts.

Comment: True here, but this API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/change-the-billing-state-of-a-subscription-for-a-user) lets the developer initiate the refund for the user, (note there is `Refund` changeType of all four). I am concerned about what is refunded in the particular case.

Comment: Don't worry, this API initiates a refund request. Only qualified subscriptions will be refunded. The specific conditions are judged by Microsoft. If the goods do not meet the refund conditions, the request will fail.